# Why does zsh open a file descriptor off by one?

Tags: shell, zsh, file-descriptors

I can open a file descriptor explicitly the normal way:

```
$ ls -lh /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:06 0 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:06 1 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:06 2 -> /dev/pts/6
lr-x------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:06 3 -> /proc/31288/fd
$ exec 3<foo
$ ls -lh /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:07 0 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:07 1 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:07 2 -> /dev/pts/6
lr-x------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:07 3 -> /home/tavianator/foo
lr-x------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:07 4 -> /proc/31334/fd
```

So far so good.  `zsh` doesn't seem to support two-digit file descriptor syntax like `10<foo`, but it does support a variable substitution syntax `{fd}<foo`:

```
$ fd=10
$ exec {fd}<foo
$ ls -lh /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:08 0 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:08 1 -> /dev/pts/6
lr-x------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:08 11 -> /home/tavianator/foo
lrwx------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:08 2 -> /dev/pts/6
lr-x------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:08 3 -> /home/tavianator/foo
lr-x------ 1 tavianator users 64 Jul 10 11:08 4 -> /proc/31413/fd
```

But hold on, why is fd **11** open instead of **10**?

Comment: `s/normal way/Linux way/`.  Here's what happens on OpenBSD: `ls: /proc/self/fd: No such file or directory`.  FWIW.

Comment: @SatōKatsura Fair enough, I replaced that with `/dev/fd/` so it's more widely reproducible.

Comment: Still no go, on *BSD `/dev/fd` is populated with actual devices.  But this has nothing to do with the gist of your question.

Comment: `{fd}<foo` will *set* variable fd, not use its value.

Comment: @meuh Ah okay!  That doesn't seem to happen consistently though, `fd=30; ls -lh /dev/fd/ {fd}<foo; echo $fd` prints `30` but `fd=30; true {fd}<foo; echo $fd` prints `11`, `12`, etc.

Comment: It seems to depend on whether the command is built-in or not. It works in bash for `ls` it seems.

Comment: @meuh Indeed, `/usr/bin/true` behaves the same as `ls`.  Seems strange to me.  I'm also quite surprised that the fds in the `true` case *stay open* after the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how ZSH is written. ZSH by default duplicates a file descriptor to fd 10:

```
$ PS1='%% ' zsh -f
% lsof -p $$ | grep 10u
zsh     29192 jhqdoe   10u   CHR  136,0       0t0         3 /dev/pts/0
%
```

And subsequent fd-related code in `Src/exec.c` calls `movefd`

```
/**/
static void
addfd(int forked, int *save, struct multio **mfds, int fd1, int fd2, int rflag,
      char *varid)
{
    int pipes[2];

    if (varid) {
        /* fd will be over 10, don't touch mfds */
        fd1 = movefd(fd2);
        if (fd1 == -1) {
            zerr("cannot moved fd %d: %e", fd2, errno);
            return;
```

which over in `Src/utils.c` does the duplicate-to-the-next-available-above-10-which-is-already-taken-by-default-so-the-first-you'll-see-is-11 thing:

```
movefd(int fd)
{
    if(fd != -1 && fd < 10) {
#ifdef F_DUPFD
        int fe = fcntl(fd, F_DUPFD, 10);
#else
        int fe = movefd(dup(fd));
#endif
```

My `zsh` according to `strace` is using the `fcntl` code path, though I suspect from the comments that either `fcntl(...` or `movefd(dup(...` will result in new fd starting at 11; 10 is not available as zsh by default holds a duplicate at that number.

All the `{somelabel}` does is to obtain the lowest available file descriptor greater than 10; this could be 11 or may instead be some higher number depending on what else the shell already has open:

```
% exec {foo}>asdf
% echo $foo
11
% exec {quer}>asdf
% echo $quer
12
...
```

Comment: Ah okay, perhaps I have misinterpreted the intent of the `{fd}<file` syntax?  `3<file`, `4<file`, `5<file` etc. all do what I expect.  Can I get that behaviour for fds bigger than 9 in some way?

Comment: Not really, but you can get whatever fd number happens to be associated with `{foo}` via `$foo`