# Does fd number of various shells fixed?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, file-descriptors, dash

Let's say:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ echo 'ls -l /proc/$$/fd | grep a.sh' > a.sh; \
> while IFS='' read -r f; do \
> echo "$f"; "$f" a.sh; \
> done < <(tail -n +2 /etc/shells)
/bin/sh
lr-x------ 1 xiaobai xiaobai 64 Jan  20 00:09 10 -> /tmp/a.sh
/bin/dash
lr-x------ 1 xiaobai xiaobai 64 Jan  20 00:09 10 -> /tmp/a.sh
/bin/bash
lr-x------ 1 xiaobai xiaobai 64 Jan  20 00:09 255 -> /tmp/a.sh
/bin/rbash
lr-x------ 1 xiaobai xiaobai 64 Jan  20 00:09 255 -> /tmp/a.sh
/bin/zsh
lr-x------ 1 xiaobai xiaobai 64 Jan  20 00:09 11 -> /tmp/a.sh
/usr/bin/zsh
lr-x------ 1 xiaobai xiaobai 64 Jan  20 00:09 11 -> /tmp/a.sh
/bin/ksh93
lr-x------ 1 xiaobai xiaobai 64 Jan  20 00:09 10 -> /tmp/a.sh
/bin/rksh93
lr-x------ 1 xiaobai xiaobai 64 Jan  20 00:09 10 -> /tmp/a.sh
xb@dnxb:/tmp$
```

Does bash always has fixed fd number 255 and zsh has fixed  fd number 11 by default ?

I ask this question because I need to extract the full path executed from any shell processes. I wonder I can hard-coded my script to refer this fixed numbers or not.

Note that this is for personal script and not means to run on critical business, so I'm not looking for 100% reliable, but **does the fd number fixed on most of the cases** ?

**[UPDATE]:**

The reason why I don't parse the `cmdline` is because:

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/bash
cat "/proc/$$/cmdline" | tr '\0' '\n'
readlink -f /proc/$$/fd/255

xb@dnxb:~/Downloads$ bash --norc foo.sh --norc
bash
--norc
foo.sh
--norc
/home/xiaobai/Downloads/foo.sh
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads$
```

As you can see, only `fd` able to give the full path `/home/xiaobai/Downloads/foo.sh`, but not the `cmdline`. And the script can't distinguish either `foo.sh` or `--norc` is a path or an option since `foo.sh` can appear at any option position, unless I do ugly checking such as it's not startswith `--`.

While `fd` has no problem to produces the correct full path even I do `bash --norc foo.sh --norc foo2.sh`.

Anyway, I just realized my task don't have to check this since I noticed no system processes except custom process are inherited from shell. But still any answer will help to future reader.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377514/117549

Comment: Rather than describing your approach to answering your own question, I suggest that you edit the question to tell is what you're trying to accomplish.  I don't understand how "full path executed from any shell process" has anything to do with open files.

Comment: @AndyDalton I learn this trick from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16131743/1074998 . What I want to do is get the path (and also executed path if it's shell) of all running process pid and then use dpkg-query to print the package description, manual, filetype into single file. I just done similar concept for a specific directory at  https://github.com/limkokhole/binaries_brief, but now I want to apply it on all running processes too.

Comment: If you want the path of the process, couldn't you look at `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`?

Comment: @AndyDalton But I have no way to distiguish between parameters with executing path from cmdline. And I figure out fd example can get the path, i.e. /tmp/a.sh

Comment: The first token would be the command, everything else would be a parameter.  If it's a shell script, the first token would be the shell, the first parameter will be the script, and the rest will be parameters to that script.  In the general case, I don't understand how looking at `/proc/<pid/fd` is going to tell you anything about the command itself.

Comment: @AndyDalton So the first parameter is always the script even though the parameter put in between ? I'm not on my machine now and will check later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can be sure of is that it won't be fds 1 to 9 as those are reserved for use by the user in POSIX sh implementations and 0 could be used in the `sh < your-script` case. yash extends it to fds 1 to 99.

You can't rely on it being a fixed value, as the shell will use a different one if that fd was already open upon start. Most shells seem to use the first free fds above 9 (or 99 for yash) for their internal fds. `bash` seems to be using 255 and going down rather than up when it can't use it:

```
bash-5.0$ bash a 255> /dev/null
total 0
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 0 -> /dev/pts/12
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 1 -> /dev/pts/12
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 2 -> /dev/pts/12
lr-x------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 254 -> /home/chazelas/a
l-wx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 255 -> /dev/null
bash-5.0$ ulimit -n 123
bash-5.0$ bash a
total 0
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 0 -> /dev/pts/12
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 1 -> /dev/pts/12
lr-x------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 122 -> /home/chazelas/a
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Sep 26 18:03 2 -> /dev/pts/12
```

Using `$0` to get the path of the script being executed is usually the best approach. See also: [Will $0 always include the path to the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119929)

Comment: Actually my script checking all processes, so I can't insert `$0` into arbitrary script, but still you've answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above, you might be able to use `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` to get the information in which you're interested.  Note that the tokens are NIL-character delimited, so you'll have to process the output a bit:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline | tr "\0" " "
```

So, if for instance I have:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $(cat "/proc/$$/cmdline" | tr "\0" " ")
```

Here are some sample runs:

```
$ bash foo.sh
bash foo.sh

$ ./foo.sh
/bin/bash ./foo.sh

$ ./foo.sh 1 2 3 4
/bin/bash ./foo.sh 1 2 3 4
```

Note that that doesn't always get you the full path to the binary.  For that, you could look at `/proc/<pid/exe`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe
... /proc/12345/exe -> /bin/bash
```

That may not be what you're after, I just don't understand how looking at the open file descriptors is going to give you what you want.

Comment: Hi, I just tested and noticed it still same problem from what I worry, e.g.: `bash --norc foo.sh`, the executing path `foo.sh` do not appear on the 1st parameter and no way to know which one is the path (Unless I check it startswith `-`, but I'm not sure is portable for all shells or not, which some shells may allow option without `-`). Second thing is, the path is not a full path (I know exe will shows `/bin/bash`, but what I worry is `foo.sh` is not a absolute path).

Comment: I just do a quick check with `ps auxfww`, I noticed I don't have to worry it, since there are no system processes(excluded my custom script) inherited from shell. But still if someone can give a solution it may helpful to future reader.

Comment: *the executing path foo.sh do not appear on the 1st parameter* then it's relative to the working dir of the process (/proc/{id}/cwd) that you can use as a prefix to the shell script.